# CiviCRM CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fails on UNION (diff number of columns)

Tags: civicrm

I've got CiviCRM 5.10.4 running on Drupal 7.65, and one particular function ("Subscriber Donor Report") is blowing up on an underlying SQL error. I turned on debugging, and following is what I see. Looks like a hard-core internals problem that I could never deal with on my own. Incidentally, this problem has persisted across several updates of Civi (since 5.4 maybe?) and also Drupal (at least since 7.60). Is there any hope? Could this possibly be caused by some weird data in the db? I wouldn't normally think so.

```
Database Error Code: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns, 1222
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
(SELECT * FROM civicrm_tmp_e_dflt_0441f87ccf495b6b8c955d3a4407fde6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM civireport_contribution_detail_temp2) [nativecode=1222 ** The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
(SELECT * FROM civicrm_tmp_e_dflt_0441f87ccf495b6b8c955d3a4407fde6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM civireport_contribution_detail_temp2) [nativecode=1222 ** The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
(SELECT * FROM civicrm_tmp_e_dflt_0441f87ccf495b6b8c955d3a4407fde6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM civireport_contribution_detail_temp2) [nativecode=1222 ** The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns]"]
)
```

```
#0 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(190): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#3 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#4 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...", "1222 ** The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns")
#7 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#9 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#10 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#11 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#12 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1413): CRM_Core_DAO->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...", TRUE)
#13 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(3710): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...", (Array:0))
#14 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Detail.php(568): CRM_Report_Form->executeReportQuery("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_contribution_detail_temp3  DEFAULT CHARACTE...")
#15 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(2816): CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Detail->beginPostProcessCommon()
#16 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(3473): CRM_Report_Form->beginPostProcess()
#17 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(886): CRM_Report_Form->postProcess()
#18 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(585): CRM_Report_Form->preProcess()
#19 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#20 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Detail), "display")
#21 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Detail), "display")
#22 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#23 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#24 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php(89): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Contribute_Detail", NULL, (Array:0))
#25 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run((Array:4), NULL)
#26 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#27 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#28 <path>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#29 <path>/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("report", "instance", "4")
#30 <path>/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#31 {main}
```

Comment: You will tend to get far quicker responses on http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thanks! I didn't realize I was in the wrong place... I thought that just tagging would bring the appropriate attention to it. Will repost now...

Comment: hundreds more eyeballs in the channel ;-)